# declaring / compiling 2d vector of vectors

Tags: c++

A colleague has provided me with a package of c++ code based on some Celestrak satellite code https://celestrak.org/software/vallado/cpp.zip.

In several places the code, i.e coordfk5.cpp declares vectors of vectors like

```
std::vector< std::vector<double> > prec, nut(3,3), st, stdot, pm, pmp
```

The nut(3,3) and similar declarations won't compile on my system yet does for the colleague on his and presumably others who have downloaded the original package.

> stl_vector.h: In instantiation of 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_initialize_dispatch(_Integer, _Integer, std::__true_type) [with _Integer = int; _Tp = std::vector; _Alloc = std::allocatorstd::vector<double >]':
> stl_vector.h:404:55:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const allocator_type&) [with _InputIterator = int; _Tp = std::vector; _Alloc = std::allocatorstd::vector<double >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocatorstd::vector<double >]'
> stl_vector.h:1166:59: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vectorstd::vector<double >::_M_fill_initialize(std::vectorstd::vector<double >::size_type, int&)'
> _M_fill_initialize(static_cast<size_type>(__n), __value);

I'm on gcc version 4.8.1, the colleague is on 4.6.3. I've tried adding -std=c++98 etc options to no avail.

I can get the code to compile by changing to eg

```
 nut(3,std::vector<double>(3))
```

but not sure if this is right as the code then seg faults.

So two questions,

Is it possible with some options/switches to compile the code as is?

If not any idea how these vectors should be declared and set-up?

Comment: "won't compile on my system yet does for the colleague". Do you use different compilers?

Comment: Did you try with -std=c++11?

Comment: It doesn't look legal to me. The second parameter needs to be a value type which, in this case, is a `std::vector<double>`. Try substituting it for this: `std::vector< std::vector<double> > nut(3, std::vector<double>(3));`. It may be your friend has an implementation with a non-standard constructor? **REFERENCE:** http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: So, I'm assuming the software comes with no Makefile or build instructions?

Comment: @SimonOroño GCC 4.6 doesn't use `-std=c++11`.

Comment: The code is including `<vector.h>` which is not standard C++. There's your problem.

Comment: Colleague at different institute so different machine and compiler. Tried -std=c++11 no joy. Already tried std::vector< std::vector<double> > nut(3, std::vector<double>(3)); which as mentioned compiles but seg faults. No makefile or build file :( thanks Ad

Comment: OK turns out changing to  nut(3, std::vector<double>(3)) was indeed the fix. The seg fault was caused by a missing data file nut80,dat! Sorry, just assumed the seg fault was the result of messing with the declaration

Answer (score 0):

The `nut(3,3)` attempts to use `3` as initializer for the inner `std::vector<int>`.

However, `std::vector` has an `explicit` constructor which is why it doesn't compile. As you have found, explicit constructors have to have the type explicitly written, with `nut(3, std::vector<int>(3))`.

Some older compilers came with a `vector` that didn't mark the constructor as `explicit` which would explain your colleagues' observations.